# How to best store a timestamp or date in a database?

Tags: java, sql, database

When I need to store time/date information, how is it best to be stored in a database?
If I store them as a `String` representation e.g. get current timestamp (using `Date` for example) and store the `String` representation in the DB is it a good idea?
What is the best practice for this? What are any cons?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best practice is to use a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATE` type in the database. All major database vendors support these SQL standard data types.

Apart from performance and storage optimisation, you'll gain expressiveness and you'll be able to use a lot of datetime manipulation functions and operations directly in the database, depending on the database you're using. Think about comparing dates, adding dates, adding intervals to dates (e.g. what day is tomorrow), etc...

Note that...

- If you're using Oracle, beware that `DATE` also contains time information
- If you're using SQLite, beware that datetime types may have numeric or text affinity. I.e. they're stored as numbers or text.
- If you're using SQL Server, Sybase (ASE and SQL Anywhere), SQLite, the dialect-specific version of the `TIMESTAMP` data type is called `DATETIME` (SQL Server's `TIMESTAMP` is actually a `VARBINARY(8)`)
- At least H2, HSQLDB, MySQL, Sybase SQL Anywhere support both `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` data type synonyms.

Comment: What do I gain over using e.g. a `String`?

Answer (score 1):

Its best to use a timestamp datatype in both MySQL and T-SQL.

Using timestamps allows you to perform calucations on the data far easier queries, addings or substrating days, months, years whatever you like. Also ordering is easier.

Timestamps also contain a timezone part to, so if you ever need to internationalise your site it would be easier.

Most languages such as PHP also have functions to display timestamps in a format of your choosing so you can convert timestamps to more readable formats.

Finally javascript/jquery plugins often require full timestamps to perform calculations on dates and times jQuery timeago for example.

Comment: Beware that in (SQL Server's) T-SQL, `timestamp` is actually a `varbinary(8)`... The SQL timestamp data type is called `datetime` in T-SQL...

Comment: @Matthew Riches How can we get a timezone from the timestamp ?

Answer (score 1):

The Best practice is use the DATE / TIMESTAMP datatype available from your database vendor, one of the benefits of having the essential datatype is that "in future you can query for date time specific conditions", for example in future you may require to

1. Generate a report of a specific month/year
2. Generate report between two dates i.e between 01/05/11 and 01/02/12 etc.
3. To display date wise report (i.e.total sales on 15th August,11), all though this can also be done using String datatype, I think that date comparison are much faster than of String representations (char or Varchar etc).
   4.....

Apart from above conditions, they are many more cases for which it is wiser to use Date ? TimeStamp instead of String....