# Dynamic Javascript/JSON to show (game) server status

Tags: javascript, json, status

I own multiple game servers as well as a website to display the server status.

The problem is that the website (server status page) is slow as it needs to ping/fetch data from a remote IP every single time the page is load.

I've seen other places do this such as [here](http://minecraftpvp.com/hunger-games) where they use dynamic JSON ([here](http://minecraftpvp.com/api/ping.json)) to fetch the server status.

The one shown above seems to load instantly and I am wondering how exactly this can be achieved?

Basically, I want to fetch the server status without it causing major lag every time it wants to load it (preferably similar to the one above simply because it works well).

Comment: And the question is? What have you tried?

Comment: Like I said before, I've tried one using PHP which will basically ping and fetch the data from the server via the game's port. That is extremely slow when loading as it isn't hosted on the same server as the website. The question is; 'How can JSON used similarly to the one I provided in order to fetch server status (ie. the ping, player count, etc.)'

Comment: An answer now would sound very much like an opinion. Any code you can share ? You see, latency can be caused by multiple factors (bad code, slow server etc. etc.)

Comment: How about initially loading the page without doing any pinging and then invoke every ping to a server with an individual ajax request?

Comment: Sreenath Soman, the lag isn't caused by corrupt, messy or "bad" code nor is the server slow in any way. It's simply as one is hosted in a different location to the other therefore when connecting from one to the other, there will be 300MS delays whereas without any connecting remotely pages load near to instant.

Comment: Surely initially loading the page would then cause delay when showing stats after the page has loaded? With the site I gave ([here](http://minecraftpvp.com/api/ping.json)), they seem to be able to generate the 'ping.json' file instantly without delay.

Comment: I'm happy with any simple solution. I just simply want to display the server's status without a major delay in page load. Ie. store the status in a database and include a file that displays the status.

Comment: which port are you pulling the JSON data from ? using http ?

Comment: Port 80 (HTTP) is the port I will pull the JSON data from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking and timing the example you have posted (with a biased mind, I admit).
I think (and thought before testing): they have some code running on the server that generates this data every 2 seconds. This simply means every time you call the json-script, the site simply returns the data that already exist (like ping).

They might even log all this data, so the json ping call simply returns the last entry. That should give an almost instant answer and predictable loadtime and it is how I would do it.

Good Luck!

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I was wondering about! I didn't even think to check the timing. I believe that they are using a cron job to run the update script (for the JSON) every 2 seconds - or is there a better way to update you suggest using?

Comment: Thank you! Cronjob would be fine!

Comment: @MHmk much better thing is caching results instead of cron. Some years ago i made same thing for CS servers. Cron it's bad solution because you can't show LIVE results :)

Comment: How exactly would you go about caching the results?! Surely there would be no need to cache the results if you have already set the JSON to the results?

Comment: When user visit your site ping server and save results to some cache file. Set cache for 10-30 seconds. That's it

Comment: What ever you'd like: but a database would be the fastest. You could also echo the last line of a txt-file if you'd wanted. But then you also must deceide: create a json-string from this last line, or store the json directly to the txt-file. I'd go db-style. EDIT: it also depends on whether you'd like to store a log or not.

Comment: As in, store all the results (pings, player count, etc.) in the database then output the database's results via JSON. It will then update the results in the database meaning new results?

Comment: Insert new record for each time the server status is scanned. Always display the latest record, check the timestamp to see how old the data is.

Comment: You need to make a choice: have a log that is stored in a DB or FILE (and return the last entry of the log). OR don't have a log: only store (and send to browser) the last result. In that case I'd not use a database AND have the cronjob write the json-data directly to the file.

Comment: Check my answer - i wrote file-cache example

Comment: Thanks to all and also thanks Sreenath & Peter for the caching ideas. All the help was much appreciated!

Comment: Also, something I've always wondered is how do you recommend you store timestamps in a database? I've always debated using BIGINT or DATETIME.

Comment: bigint. that IS a timestamp in data to the computer. That 'll work untill 2038-01-19

Comment: This whole thread sounds like a big opinionfest :D. @Mhmk check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800592/how-to-best-store-a-timestamp-or-date-in-a-database

Comment: It does sound like lots of opinions although it's very interesting reading other people's perspectives. I'm also learning a lot. Anyways, I think I am done pestering people! Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome! @ Sreenath Soman: Yes, there are opinions, but sometimes one needs options to choose from. There is nothing wrong with that, and I do feel this question has value to future readers, including Peter Szymkowski's script.

Comment: I have a slight problem now regarding this method. I basically _need_ to 'run a script (possibly PHP?) every 5 seconds to update the JSON file' - although I am unsure how I can run the script automatically as cron jobs can't go below 1 minute... Will I need to make another program to update this and run constantly or is there another way that the example site is using? Preferably as efficient as possible.

Comment: Indeed, cronjobs have a granular time-window of 1 minute. So have the 5 second timing LOOP inside your script. A sleeping script doesn't consume CPU, though it do consume RAM. Restarted the script by a cron job every minute if it is not already running. Tweaking optimal performance (timings) would require you to keep in mind the script's maximum allowed execution-time.

Answer (score 1):

Make two files:

1: PHP Script "ping.php" for pinging which output data like this:

```
$ip = $_REQUEST['ip'];
$cache_file = "ping_{$ip}.json";

if(@filemtime($cache_file) >= (time() - 30)) {
   echo file_get_contents($cache_file);
   return ;
}

// cache is too old. now ping your server 

$json = json_encode(Array(
   'ip' => $ip,
   'players' => $players_count
));

// save new cache
file_put_contents($cache_file, $json);

// output JSON
echo $result;
```

2: HTML + jQuery

```
<table id="servers">
<tr>
<td class="ip">1.2.3.4:1234</td>
<td class="players"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ip">1.2.3.4:1234</td>
<td class="players"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ip">1.2.3.4:1234</td>
<td class="players"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#servers tr').each(function(){
  var ip = $(this).find('td.ip').text();
  var $players = $(this).find('td.players');
  $players.html('loading');

  // use ping.php to get count of players etc
  $.get('ping.php?ip='+ip, function(data){
    $players.html(data.players);
  }});
</script>
```

Simply use AJAX request for each server. `ping.php` will return server status.